# SwiftUI animations with delay

Tags: swiftui

I have an array of 5 letters and I need to show each letter sliding in one at a time from left to right with 5 seconds between each, cycling in a continuous loop but showing no more than 5 letters.

Here's what I have so far, but I'm stuck. This doesn't seem like it should be too difficult...what am I missing?  Thanks!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
            
    @State private var letters = ["S","T","A","R","T"]
    @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 5, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {

            HStack {
                ForEach(self.letters, id:\.self) { letter in
                    Text(letter)
                        .font(.custom("Menlo", size: 18))
                        .fontWeight(.black)
                        .frame(width: 38, height: 38, alignment: .center)
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .shadow(radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)
                        .transition(AnyTransition.slide)
                        .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatCount(1))
                }
            }
        }
        .onReceive(timer) {_ in
            //????? should I use this? where and how?
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: What should happen after all 5 characters are on screen?  Should they leave one at a time?

Comment: Yes, they should exit to the right as a new letter comes in from the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to animate the characters onto the screen, they need to be offscreen first.  That means you need to build up the array of letters your `ForEach` is showing.

I made the letters `Identifiable` giving them unique `id`s so that it wouldn't confuse the first `T` in `START` with the second `T`.

I'm using an `offset` for `animation` instead of `slide`.  The `arriving` property of a letter is used to decide the direction of the `offset`.

[image]

```
struct Letter: Identifiable {
    let letter: String
    var arriving: Bool
    let id = UUID()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var start = [" ","S","T","A","R","T"].map { Letter(letter: $0, arriving: true) }
    @State private var letters = [Letter]()
    @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 2, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {

            HStack {
                ForEach(self.letters) { letter in
                    Text(letter.letter)
                        .font(.custom("Menlo", size: 18))
                        .fontWeight(.black)
                        .frame(width: 38, height: 38, alignment: .center)
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .shadow(radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)
                        .transition(AnyTransition.offset(x: letter.arriving ? -250 : 250))
                        .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatCount(1))
                }
            }
        }
        .onReceive(timer) {_ in
            print("TIMER")
        
            var letter = start.removeLast()
            letter.arriving = true
            letters.indices.forEach { idx in letters[idx].arriving = false }
            letters = [letter] + letters
            if letters.count > 5 {
                let last = letters.removeLast()
                start = [last] + start
            }
        }
    }
}
```